# Compare mongoose ObjectId in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I've an array of ObjectId, which is declared as following in mongoose schema.

```
array: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
```

So this array contains ObjectIds of other Object named `User`.

Now I want to check whether a specific Object of `User` is in this array or not. Initially I've tried following loop:

```
var flag = false;
for(const usr in array){
    if(usr == user) flag = true;
}
```

But this never set the flag. I've also tried comparing them with `===`. But no results.

Then I've tried `underscore.js` as following:

```
var flag = false;
for(const usr in array){
        if(underscore.isMatch(user, usr)){
        flag = true;
        break;  
    } 
}
```

This always sets flag to true even if the array is empty. So what I'm missing here? I'm really a newbie in javascript and node js.